# v-if property not updating in VUE.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, onblur

1I'm trying to validate a text box. I have a child component that has an on blur event. And a v-if statement to show an error if true. The on blur gets triggered fine and I step through the code. It seems to do what I want however the error property on the parent component/v-if statement, is not updating (showing the error), Here is my code:

```
//Child component
    <template>
        <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="input-username"
          name="custid"
          v-on:blur="$emit('hasValidCustomerId')"
          v-model="custid"/>     

        <div v-if="custidError"> Error! </div>
    <template/>
//Parent Component
 <div id="password-form">
            <transition name: currentTransition>
                <component 
                       v-on:changeSlide="changeSlide" 
                        v-on:blur="$emit('hasValidCustomerId')" 
                       :is="slides[currentSlide]">
                </component>
            </transition>
        </div>
```

My javascript

```
// Child Component
    var accountDetails =
      {
        template: '#template',
        components: { },
        data: function () {     
         return {
                custid: '',
               custidError: false,
               currentSlide: 0,
                currentTransition: ''
     };          
      },                      
        computed: {},
        methods: {},
      };    
// Parent Component
      var passwordFlow =
        {
        template: '#template',
        components: {
            "login": login,
            "account-details": accountDetails,
            "otc-options": otcOptions
        },
        data: function () {     
          return {
              slides: ['login', 'account-details', 'otc-options'],
              currentSlide: 0, 
              currentTransition: ' '
              custid: '',
              custidError: false 
             };     
          },             

        computed: {},
        methods: {
             hasValidCustomerId: function () {
                if (this.custid === " ")
                    this.custidError = true;        ///This gets set to true
                  console.log(this.custidError);    ///this logs false ??               
            },
      };
```

VUE instance

```
        el: "#login-main",
       data: {},
       components: {
           "passwordFlow": passwordFlow,
            },
       computed: {},
       mounted: function () { },
       methods: {}
   });
```

Comment: A few things. Only the parent component updates `custidError` and the child has no visibility to this (it is not being passed as a prop). Also, in your `hasValidCustomerId` function, since you don't have `{}` around your `if` block, the `console.log` will be called every time, regardless (hence the `false` in the logs). Log out your `custid` too and you'll see it doesn't equal `" "`.

Comment: I wrapped the if statement in brackets.And you were correct, I logged custid it printed nothing. But now It's not hitting the on blur function at all. What do you mean only the parent is updated? What would I need to change? I updated my code to show I am emitting the onBlur function to the parent. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

in child component , change `custidError` from data to props

```
// Child Component
    var accountDetails =
      {
        template: '#template',
        components: { },
        props: {
         custidError: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        }
       },
        data: function () {     
         return {
                custid: '',
               currentSlide: 0,
                currentTransition: ''
     };          
      },                      
        computed: {},
        methods: {},
      };
```

then in parent , pass it to component

```
<component :custidError="custidError"
                       v-on:changeSlide="changeSlide" 
                        v-on:blur="$emit('hasValidCustomerId')" 
                       :is="slides[currentSlide]">
                </component>
```